# Extend type declaration from imported module

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to extend the `PlatformOSType` from react-native for my app. Is there a way to do it without patching react-native/index.d.ts file?
I tried the approach with declaring module in my local d.ts but it seems like it overwrites all react-native declarations where I just need to extend a single type.

index.d.ts

```js
declare module "react-native" {
  export type PlatformOSType = import("react-native").PlatformOSType | "samsung_tv" | "lg_tv"
}
```

Comment: This looks like a recursive definition to me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the existing types, as far as I know, you need to import them at the beginning of your `.d.ts` file like this:

```js
import 'react-native';

declare module "react-native" {
  export type PlatformOSType = import("react-native").PlatformOSType | "samsung_tv" | "lg_tv"
}
```